# Parallels: ‚Unable to connect to Hard Disk 0’ on Virtual machine's start

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machines

I have a virtual machine (Windows 7) running wth parallels.

Today I wanted to start the VM and now I always get an error when it starts up:

> Unable to connect to Hard Disk 0 on Virtual machine's start

I can‘t start the VM, I tried booting Windows from my recovery disk and repairing the hard disk. But nothing works.

Comment: What do the logs say? Is the VM Disk actually available on your file-system? What happens if you double click the VM disk?

Comment: No the VM Disk is not available on the file-system. And if I try to double click the disk, it tries to mount it. But then I also get an error message saying that it couldn't be mounted.

Comment: Your statement contradicts itself. Either the VM disk is there, or it's not. If it's not there, then you can't load a missing file. If it's there, double-clicking it *should* load parallels, but if that's failing, or not opening it, it could be a damaged VM container.

Comment: The VM disk is there but I can't load or mount it. When I double click it it tries to open Parallels Mounter but then I get the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The VM disk is there but I can't load or mount it. When I double click it it tries to open Parallels Mounter but then I get the error message.

Sounds like a corrupted VM disk. You might want to contact Parallels to see if they have any options to recover it. Otherwise, you'll have to deploy a new VM and restore from a backup.

You may also be able to create a new VM with the same configuration, but choose an existing VM disk during the HDD phase; choose the one you already have. If this also fails, it's toast.

Comment: I tried _You may also be able to create a new VM with the same configuration, but choose an existing VM disk during the HDD phase; choose the one you already have. If this also fails, it's toast._ But even then I can't load the disk. Are there no other options than contacting Parallels?

Comment: From the information provided, it sounds like the VM container is corrupted. If you can extract an **EXACT** error (from logs) then you *might* be able to Google for a solution, but as far as I can tell, this container is corrupted. Contacting Parallels might provide something helpful, or they'll tell you the same thing... Build a new VM and restore from backup.